# Load images and text of html in textview[html is dynamic getting from server]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

dBinding.desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(ticket.getDescription()));
dBinding.desc.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Answer (score 0):

You can`t load image with html in textView if you want to show html with text and image you should use WebView and load html into it.
emaple:

```
String yourData = "html tags";
webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

reference : [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))